# Spyder IDE plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, ide, spyder

I use Anaconda Spyder IDE, I was wondering if anyone knows how does Spyder plots really work? I can visualise any graph which is a matplotlib figure instance on spyder plots. However I did try to use Dexplot which creates matplotlib figure instance but I cannot visualise anything in the Spyder plot but I can save the graph as pdf.

[Dexplot doesn`t show any plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613011/dexplot-doesnt-show-any-plot)

Any suggestion why this can happen? Could be something to do in the way Spyder plots work?

Comment: I had a _brief_ look at `dexplot` … well, do you have any COMPELLING reasons to use it over `seaborn`?

Comment: There are couple of type of graphs I would like to use. However I honestly don't get why it doesn't work on spyder plots even if dexplot creates mathplotlib figure instance.

Comment: Then look at its source code and reimplement, you'll learn and in the end you'll save time.

Comment: OK I will have a go. It will take me weeks most probably. So the main problem is the source code, something to do with the plot visualisation in jupyter vs spyder.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You probably need to configure Dexplot to generate static images (png's or svg's) so that they appear in our Plots pane. The examples you provided are rendered in the notebook, which probably means they are web-based ones and those can't handled by Spyder yet.